# How to set product's sale & regular price programmatically in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I need to change the product's regular and sale price in WooCommerce.

I can update the regular price using:

```
update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', 500 );
```

But I want to change sale price also. Some products don't have a `_sale` meta key, so I can't do the same thing I did to regular price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually using the old way to set product prices… There are 2 ways:

###### A) Using this old way,

1. to set the regular price only, you should use:

   ```
   update_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', 500 );
   update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', 500 );
   ```
2. to set the sale price and the regular price, you should use:

   ```
   update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price', 450 );
   update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', 450 );
   update_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', 500 );
   ```

###### B) The new way *(Since WooCommerce 3)*:

As WooCommerce is migrating to custom tables, and for other reasons, it's better to use all available **WC_Product setter methods**…

For product prices, you will use the following:

```php
// Get an instance of the WC_Product object
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

$regular_price = 500; // Define the regular price
$sale_price    = 465; // Define the sale price (optional)

// Set product sale price
if ( isset($sale_price) && ! empty($sale_price) ) {
    $product->set_sale_price($sale_price);

    $product->set_price($sale_price); // Set active price with sale price
} else {
    $product->set_price($regular_price); // Set active price with regular price
}
// Set product regular price
$product->set_regular_price($regular_price);

// Sync data, refresh caches and saved data to the database
$product->save();
```